# Unable to find data for class 'org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer'

Tags: spring-boot, gretty

I am getting this strange error while trying to start Spring Boot application in Servlet container.

The same WAR starts normally in standalone Tomcat server, but gives the error seen below if started using Gretty Gradle plugin

Any ideas that it means?

Spring-boot 1.3.3, Gradle 2.12, Gretty 1.2.4, Tomcat 8

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:104)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    ...
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springsource.loaded.UnableToLoadClassException: Unable to find data for class 'org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer'
    at org.springsource.loaded.Utils.loadSlashedClassAsBytes(Utils.java:787)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getDescriptorFor(TypeRegistry.java:311)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptorFor(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:124)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.findTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:140)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.walkHierarchyForCatchersAndSuperDispatchers(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:152)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.computeCatchersAndSuperdispatchers(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:219)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:81)
    at org.sprce.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor.extract(TypeDescriptorExtractor.java:51)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.addType(TypeRegistry.java:912)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:302)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:102)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in Gretty related to classloading. 
Starting Gretty with WAR e.g. `gradlew appRunWar` allows to work around it.

There are multiple bugs opened for it:

- https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/199
- https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/209
- https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/148